# ¿Qué quiere decir "La neta, aquí son bien chidos"?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, méxico, el-salvador

[Me encontré](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40856961#40856961) hace poco con esta imagen subida por alguien con raíces mexicanas:

[image]

Es decir:

> **La neta, aquí son bien chidos.**

Mirando el DAMER veo que "chido" significa:

> [**chido, -a.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chido)
>   I.  1.  adj. Mx. Bonito, lindo. pop. (shido).
>   2.  Mx. Muy bueno. pop. (shido).

Y "neta":

> [**neta.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=neta)
>   I.  1.  f. Mx, Gu, ES; Ec, Ch, juv. Verdad, pureza. pop + cult → espon ^ fest.
>   II. 1.  ES. Conclusión.
>   ■
>   a. ǁ    la ~ del planeta. f. Mx. La verdad indubitable, clara y sin tergiversación. pop + cult → espon ^ fest.
>   □
>   a. ǁ    la ~. loc. sust. Mx. Persona que posee los mejores atributos morales y que se considera un amigo leal.
>
> neto, -a.
>   I.  1.  adj. Mx. Referido a persona, que habla con toda sinceridad. pop + cult → espon ^ fest.

Tirando de las entradas propias de México, parece que vendría a ser algo así como si en España dijéramos:

> La verdad es que son la mar de majos.

O, más en general:

> La verdad es que son buena gente.

Pero claro, dos coloquialismos en seis palabras es mucha densidad y puede que me esté perdiendo algo. ¿Qué querría decir pues?

Comment: Lo que no pillo muy bien es la foto y su relación con el texto. ¿El tipo ese es un policia?¿un segurata?

Comment: @blonfu ¿no te parece como que lo están sobornando?

Comment: No sé. Pensaba que le entrevistaban pero la foto es mala y podía ser un billete en lugar de una grabadora. No me queda claro ahora que lo dices.

Comment: @blonfu al parecer es (o era) un vigilante en una universidad. Le dicen "Pan de Dios" https://twitter.com/Memes_UDB/status/289572320207577088. Da la impresión de ser apreciado por los estudiantes, o al menos lo mencionan varias veces en publicaciones

Comment: Vale. Ahora tiene más sentido el meme, gracias @MauricioMartinez

Comment: Chido (México) = Chévere (Colombia) = Guay (España).

Comment: @fedorqui originalmente, esta frase sale de JuanM, pero cabe mencionar que él no es mexicano, tiene influencias y raíces mexicanas por su familia pero él es más *gringo* que nada ;)

Comment: Solo hay que asistir a una telenovela mexicana sobre los narcos para oir este lenguaje. Por exemplo: *La Piloto* or *Falsa Identidad*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente, se refiere a la segunda referencia de posibles significados, lo más parecido podría ser sería algo así como:

> La *verdad*, aquí son bien *buena onda*

Partiendo de la frase original, los significados de esos dos coloquialismos serían:

- La neta:

  - La verdad
- Chido:

  - Buena onda. Persona agradable, amable, que cae muy bien.
  - Alivianado. Persona no conflictiva que genera un ambiente agradable

Leyendo los [comentarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/qu%C3%A9-quiere-decir-la-neta-aqu%C3%AD-son-bien-chidos#comment37146_23063) veo que dices que pareciera algo como un soborno, pero no. Lo que yo logro identficar es más bien como si fuera una entrevista, donde el guardia solo da su opinión.

Otro [comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/qu%C3%A9-quiere-decir-la-neta-aqu%C3%AD-son-bien-chidos#comment37149_23063) que me llamó la atención, es el del Mauricio, donde indica que se refiere a un guardia de una universidad y que le llamaban *pan de dios*. Bueno, cabe mencionar que siguiendo la cuenta de Twitter se trata de una universidad de El Salvador, donde es posible que también se puedan dar estos coloquialismos. La verdad es que tenía entendido que se usaban meramente en México pero ahora veo que se ha extendido por Centroamérica. Es bueno saberlo ya que el día que visite El Salvador, me sentiré como en casa expresándome de la gente de la misma manera que en México.

Comment: Qué buena y exhaustiva respuesta, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Son palabras muy oídas en las telenovelas mexicanas cuando se trata de narcos o otros criminales.

Answer (score 3):

No soy mexicano pero he escuchado bastante las expresiones que se mencionan en la pregunta. El sentido que le das a la frase me parece el correcto. Imagino que la expresión que propones de España:

> La verdad es que son la mar de majos.

tiene un matiz más cercano a la frase de la pregunta que:

> La verdad es que son buena gente.

Esta última suena un poco más plana. Lo que quiero decir es que tanto "majo" y "chido" dan la sensasión de algo más que simplemente "ser buena gente"

Bono: en Colombia una opción sería:

> La verdad, la gente acá es bien chévere

Comment: Sí, en España se usa _la mar de_ para indicar mucha cantidad. _La mar de majos_ es muy coloquial y cercano, mientras que _buena gente_ mantiene la idea pero es más impersonal.

Answer (score 1):

LLegué de casualidad y tarde a este post, pero no puedo dejar de declarar que en Argentina sería:

> Posta, que acá la gente es re-copada